# Где расположены исходники mount в linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, opensource, mount

Интересуют исходные коды mount. Поиск по ядру и glibc не дал результатов. Подскажите, где искать?

Comment: из мана `The mount command is part of the util-linux package and is available from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.`

Answer (score 1):

из мана `The mount command is part of the util-linux package and is available from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.`

переходим по ссылке, выбираем нужную версию, выкачиваем нужный архив. 
внутри архива лежит libmount. там находятся и сорсы и документация.

также выложены на [github](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/libmount)